# Jpanel is overlapping the JFrame MenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jmenu

I have a special problem with jFrame, jPanels and Layouts.

The JFrame contains a dropdown Menu which is automatically placed into the menuarea of the JFrame.

The content area contains a JPanel with has an CardLayout.

There are 3 cards (JPanels) in this Layout.
Two of the cards are working very well. These cards are equipped with borderLayouts and do want they are thought for. Especially the JMenuBar of the JFrame is fully visible.

The third card gets also borderLayout. In the CENTER of  this layout a JPanel ist installed, which has an Gridlayout. In every Grid a JPanel is implemented and shown (as expected) on the screen.

And here ist problem: What ever I do the JMenuBar (not the JFrameTitle) gets hide by the Layout.
It's partially visible if I place the mouse cursor in this area.
The only difference to the other both cards is the use of the GridLayout.

//Constructor of the third card

```
public GrafikReport1() {
    setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(glZeilen, glSpalten, 10,10));
    //anzSmPanel = dreieckVerzeichnis.laenge();
    for (int i=0; i < anzSmPanel; i++) {
        panelListe.add(new SmallPanel(i)); 
    }
    for (int i=0; i < anzSmPanel; i++) {
        this.add(panelListe.get(i)); 
    }

    this.setVisible(true);
    repaint();
}
```

Does anyone have a tip for me?

Comment: Create a [mre] so we can copy the code into our IDE, see the problem, and try different possible solutions.

Comment: *"Does anyone have a tip for me?"* Here's two: 1) Add relevant tags. The [tag:java] tag is very relevant. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).